# Load a map in map_server

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And how can I load a map into the map server?
I'm calling:

```
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find p2os_nav)/simple_office_map.svg 0.1f"/>
```

in the launch file but I get this error:

```
[map_server-1] process has died [pid 12465, exit code 255].
log files: /home/camilla/.ros/log/8b409eb6-5feb-11e2-b202-000fb0a0b12e/map_server-1*.log
```

and nothing is published on the /map topic.
Any ideas?
Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52450/load-a-map-in-map_server/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-16**:
I tried with png and now it works!Thank you! So which are the format supported?only png and pgm?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-16**:
From the docs: Image data is read in via SDL_Image; supported formats vary, depending on what SDL_Image provides on a specific platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if svg is supported. Can you try to convert the image to something like png/pgm? In principle this procedure works for me.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0